# Brazil fines for not registering visa with Federal Police

Tags: brazil

I am on a VITEM I, a temporary visa that requires registering with the Federal Police within 30 days of entering Brazil. The cost is 300 BRL, 200 BRL of which is for an ID. It doesn't make sense to me because, by the time the ID arrives, I will already have left the country and I don't plan to return.

Also, when I leave Brazil, I guess they will check my passport to stamp it. Are there fines for not registering the visa? I have read the articles regarding the registration but couldn't find info about fines.

Edit: my visa is for 90 days only and I will stay in the country for about 60 days.

Comment: Also, what kind of VITEM are you on (there should be a number like VITEM V)? Because as a tourist you should only have VITUR (Visto Turistico), I believe all VITEMs are for employees / scientists etc.

Comment: It is a I, not for tourists. What I am wondering is if when I exit they will ask something or do I have to show proof that I registered.

Comment: @HermanToothrot you should post your edit as a separate answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to register because from the information provided by the other answer it seemed that for stays less than 90 days the penalty must not be that high. In the end I did not get a fine, the border office was a bit puzzled and I explained that I thought registering online was enough. The officer cancelled my visa, so then I re-entered with a regular tourist visa because I had only a few days left before leaving the country. It is important to note that **I didn't need the visa to perform any bureaucratic duty**, and **if you need to exit and re-enter on the same visa you have to register it before exiting**.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find one complete source, but document from Ministry of Foreign Affair about [VITEM I](https://sistemas.mre.gov.br/kitweb/datafiles/SaoFrancisco/en-us/file/vitemI.pdf) says in point 18.:

> Upon arrival in Brazil, bearers of a Temporary Visa I must register with the Brazilian Federal Police Department (Delegacia de Estrangeiros) within 30 days from date of arrival.

Also this [Consulate's website](http://houston.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/vitem_i.xml#5.%20Notes) (Houston in particular, but information on others is similar) says

> Failing to register in time will result in daily fines. If you need to be registered, it will be written on the notes on your visa label.

So it also seems you should make sure on your visa label that you indeed must register. On my visa it says explicitly that I have to register in 30 days.

I can't find information about the amount of the fine for failing to register in Brazilian sources. If you don't prolong visa and stay over 90 days, the fine is 8,25 BRL / day, up to 827,75 BRL, according to [Federal Police Website](http://www.pf.gov.br/servicos-pf/estrangeiro/prorrogacao-de-prazo-de-estada-de-turista-e-viajante-a-negocios-temporario-ii-1) (in Portuguese), so I'm expecting it's similar amount, I'll update the answer if I find this info.

From experience of my friends and mentioned websites I know that on the border you shouldn't have any problems, they will not imprison you or ban from entering the country again, you would only have to pay the fine.

Comment: Thank for the info, however it's still not clear. I made an edit to my original post. I am only staying in the country roughly 60 days, so the overstay fine does not apply. What kind of visa do you have and how much did you pay to register?

Comment: I have VITEM V (work visa), I'm staying here for at least 2 years and I had to register because I'm employed by Brazilian company. I don't remember exactly how much I paid, I think it was around 300 BRL as you said. If I find more information I'll update my answer but PF's websites are really messy...

Comment: It's a different case then, because you needed that card to be paid, open bank account, etc. I don't need any of that. Yes the PF website is not clear. Thanks